# How do you successfully get the id of any of your objects that you want in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

One piece of functionality I'm trying to build for a fantasy football app is to have a page where any logged in user can see a list of all the other teams and their scores so that you can compare your score to teams of other users. Earlier today I got some interesting advice that suggested making a function in views.py that can show any team - not just your own. The function would obviously need to get the id of the team you want to display. It sounds logical, but I can't think of how to start/implement this though.

This is the model object in question.

```
class Team(models.Model):
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    quarter_back = models.ForeignKey(Quarterback, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    running_back = models.ForeignKey(Runningback, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    wide_receiver = models.ForeignKey(Widereceiver, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    tight_end = models.ForeignKey(Tightend, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    kicker = models.ForeignKey(Kicker, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

I've tried making a function but I get a 404 error because there's no id submitted to the URL in the first place. How can you get the object's id if there is no id showing in the template's URL? If I manually type the object's id integer at the end of the URL, it does get passed and the scoreboard function can access that object, but I need this to happen automatically. But how can you do this?

```
def scoreboard(request, id):

    team = Team.objects.get(pk=id)
```

with a URL like this.

```
path('scoreboard/<int:id>', views.scoreboard, name="scoreboard")
```

Of course, it's easy to iterate through all the objects and their fields, render them out to a template, etc, but that's only half my battle. I need to be able to have scoreboard() access all teams because I need to compare all the player's names to data stored in a variable that contains each player's individual score that is pulled from an API. If a player's name is in the variable that contains all the score information, I can then assign that score to a separate variable that can be later used to calculate a team's total score. But yeah, my stumbling block is how to successfully get the id of any and all teams in the first place. Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

## first you need to get the object then you will get id of the object

## Get the object of a model

```
   `params = {"fields_in_model": values}`
   `obj = Model.objects.get(**params)`
```

## Get the Id from object

```
   `id = obj.id`
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Can you elaborate that a little bit more. I don't quite understand what it means.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still confused by this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass team object to the template(where html exists), then get id of the team object like team.id and pass this id to the href link. Finally you can get id automatically from the path you mentioned above ('scoreboard/int:id', views.scoreboard, name="scoreboard")